# Find the values of the derivatives of the integral with a variable inside its limits.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

$\require{cancel}$

#### Problem:

I have the function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$
g(x)=\int^{(1+x^2)}_{-(1+x^2)} sin(t^3)\ dt,\ x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
I would like to calculate values of $g(0)$, $g'(0)$ and $g''(0)$.

---

**Note**:
*I've tried to calculate the values on my own but I'm not sure if my results are valid.

Is it the way I should deal with integrals with variables inside their limits?*

---

#### Calculating $g(0)$:

1. $sin(x^{2k+1}),\ k \in \mathbb{N}$ is symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis
2. The limits of the integral are symmetric with respect to the point $0$.
3. Hence $g(0) = 0$.

---

#### Calculating $g'(0)$:

1. Let's define functions $f, h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
   $$
   f(x)=\int^{(x)}_{-x)} sin(t^3)\ dt,\ x \in \mathbb{R}\\
   $$
   and
   $$
   h(x)=1+x^2
   $$
2. According [to this website](http://www.mathmistakes.info/facts/CalculusFacts/learn/doi/doif.html) I should say that $g(x)=f(h(x))$. Therefore $g'(x)=f'(h(x))h'(x)$.
3. $\cancel{f'(x)=sin(x^3)-sin(-x^3)=2sin(x^3)}$ and $h'(x)=2x$.
4. $\cancel{g'(x)=2sin((1+x^2)^3))2x = 4xsin((1+x^2)^3))}$.
   *Accodring to [the answer by S.Panja-1729](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1410062/237591) it should be:  $g'(x)=2x\sin((1+x^2)^3)-2x\sin((1+x^2)^3)=0$.*
5. So $g'(0)=0$.

---

#### Calculating $g''(0)$:

1. $\cancel{g''(x)=4sin((1+x^2)^3) + 24x^2(1+x^2)cos((1+x^2)^3)}$. <s>Therefore</s> $\cancel{g''(0)=4sin(1)}$
   *Accodring to [the answer by S.Panja-1729](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1410062/237591) $g''(x)=0.$ Therefore $g''(0)=0$.*

Comment: You do no even have to compute to show $g'(0)=0$ because $g(x)$ is an even function.

Comment: Notice the symmetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If$$F(x)=\int_{g(x)}^{h(x)}f(t)\,dt$$then $$F'(x)=f(h(x)).h'(x)-f(g(x)).g'(x)$$
I think you are wrong to calculate $g'(x)$. It will be identically zero.

In your problem , $g'(x)=2x\sin\{(1+x^2)^3\}-2x\sin\{(1+x^2)^3\}=0$. So $g''(x)=0.$